# Red is blue and blue is red

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

There's an old story, probably from Dozois's yearly anthology (pre-2000), about a human who plays an alien game. IIRC, it plays like Go and the pieces are red and blue. At the end of the story, the human becomes a master from a revelation from gameplay. "Blue is red and red is blue", or something along those lines. Haven't found it, hoping someone might know the tale.

Thank you

Comment: Perhaps it's listed here? http://senseis.xmp.net/?Literature

Comment: Couldn't find it, but Jack L Chalker's, "The Messiah Choice" has this phrase in it: "black is white, blue is red, and evil is good", and Chapter 10 is entitled "A BRUTAL GAME OF CHESS". Also found Brent Weeks' "The Broken Eye" and Daniel Suarez's "Daemon", but both were published in this century.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recognized the story from your description. Couldn't remember the title, offhand, but I could remember some of the other stories which I'd first encountered in the *same* volume as that one, and so a little time on ISFDB, and a little Googling for online reviews, helped me nail it down beyond a shadow of a doubt.

**["Out There Where the Big Ships Go"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?49813)** by **Richard Cowper**. First published in *The Magazine of Fantasy & Science Fiction* (August 1979). I first read it in **[The 1980 Annual World's Best SF](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?34907)**, edited by **Donald A. Wollheim** & **Arthur W. Saha**.

I don't have a copy handy, and it looks like [this link](https://books.google.com/books?id=MFw0AgAAQBAJ&pg=PT30&lpg=PT30&dq=%22richard%20cowper%22%20%22out%20there%20where%20the%20big%20ships%20go%22&source=bl&ots=WqYI5enhf5&sig=V_Vpxeske2OOzjP4nTy02Oyx96o&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi38s_ii6_TAhWm5IMKHapAAhQQ6AEIWjAL#v=onepage&q=%22richard%20cowper%22%20%22out%20there%20where%20the%20big%20ships%20go%22&f=false) on Google Books only
reproduces the first two pages of the story, but I remember the plot pretty well, and it matches your description perfectly.

For instance, there's a sequence where the viewpoint character (a young boy) happens to meet the reigning champion of the game (I think the same guy who had learned the game from the aliens, and brought it back to Earth), the night before a key match will occur in the annual tournament to determine if the champion will finally be dethroned. The champion seems to *want* to be replaced by someone else, if they are worthy, and he uses his burning cigar as a prop, showing how one end of it can be glowing blue . . . and then cool to red . . . and making a speech to the kid about how when you get right down to it, "blue and red are the same," or something along those lines. (I can't swear to the exact wording.)

The kid subsequently repeats this odd remark to the young hotshot who's made it all the way up the ladder to challenge the reigning champion for the title . . . but this hotshot is **not** considered likely to beat the champ the way he's beaten everyone else. The hotshot is startled, and it soon becomes clear that this has somehow triggerred an intuitive leap in his mind which causes him to look at the game differently at a key moment, the next day, and thus he makes a surprisingly brilliant move which marks the moment when things turn around and he is on his way to becoming the new champion.

In the final paragraphs of the story, I believe we are assured that the kid himself, who merely served as onlooker and messenger boy in most of the plot, eventually grows up to become a reigning champion himself!

Comment: Oh goodness, I believe you got it! I too remember the bit with the cigar!